# Javascript remove button for each new input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Check the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/20xzLdkL/

Pretty much I want to have an X button next to each new generated input that would delete the new created div.

You can see in the end of the `<script>` tags I tried something but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

```js
var room = 1;
var wrapper = $(".testtt");

function add_fields() {
  room++;
  var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
  var divtest = document.createElement("div");
  divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="testtt"><div class="label">TEST ' + room + ':</div><div class="content"><span><p class="form-inline">Testing: <select class="form-control" name="test[]" style="width:70px;"> <option value="Test">TEst</option> </select> </span><span>Number: <input class="form-control" type="number" style="width:70px;" name="number[]" value="" /></p> <div class="testtt"><button id="delete">X</button></div></span></div><div>';

  objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}

$(wrapper).on("click", "#delete", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  x--;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <button type="button" id="more_fields" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="add_fields();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> click me</button>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <div id="room_fileds">
    <div>
      <div class="content">
        <p class="form-inline">Test: <select class="form-control" name="test[]" style="width:70px;"> <option>Test1</option> </select>
          <span></span>Number: <input class="form-control" type="number" style="width:70px;" name="number[]" value="<?php print $test_stinga[1] ?>" />
        </p> 
        <br>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add the code in the OP not just a link. use `<>` for demo

Comment: Please place all relevant code in the question, ideally in a working snippet. The HTML output would also be of much more use than the spaghetti PHP. If jsFiddle goes down your question will be unanswerable, and worthless for future visitors.

Comment: I'd imagine you add a `<button>` in the same way you add an `<input>`.  What specific difficulty are you having?  https://jsfiddle.net/20xzLdkL/1/

Comment: Also sanitize your fiddle with relevant part only.

Comment: @freedomn-m Adding a new button each time wouldn't be a problem. I simply don't know how can I use javascript to delete the new created div when the button is pressed.

Comment: You clearly state *"I want to have an X button next to each new generated input"* - nothing about what that button should do.   Give the button a class and add a delegated event handler.

Comment: @freedomn-m Well , thats why I posted the question here. I need help in creating that 'delegated event handler' because I literally don't know what  you are talking about.

Comment: Ok, question was about how to add a button, now it's about event handlers on a button you've added...   ideally you should ask a new question rather than change the existing one (but there's no answers yet, so I guess it's ok).  If it's about handling events for a dynamically added button, then it's already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="form-group">
                          <button type="button" id="more_fields" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="add_fields();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> click me</button>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div id="room_fileds">
                              <div>
                                  <label>how the hell do i add a remove button for each new generated input?</label>
                                  <div class="content">

                                      <?php
                                      function not_empty_string($s) {
                                          return $s !== " ";
                                      }
                                      $pieces = array_filter(explode(",", $test_stingu),'not_empty_string');

                                      foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
                                          $test_stinga = array_filter(explode("-", $piece),'not_empty_string');
                                          // scoate spatiul de la inceputul stringului
                                          $test_stinga=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $test_stinga);
                                         ?>
                                          
                                          <p class="form-inline">Test: <select class="form-control" name="test[]" style="width:70px;"> <option>Test1</option> </select>
                                          <span></span><span>Number: <input class="form-control" type="number" style="width:70px;" name="number[]" value="<?php print $test_stinga[1] ?>"/></span><button>
                                          Button
                                          </button>
                                          </p>

                                              <br>
                                      
<?php

                    
                                          }

                                          ?>


                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div></div>
                  <script>
                      var room = 1;
                      var wrapper         = $(".testtt");
                      function add_fields() {
                          room++;
                          var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
                          var divtest = document.createElement("div");
                          divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="testtt"><div class="label">TEST ' + room + ':</div><div class="content"><span><p class="form-inline">Testing: <select class="form-control" name="test[]" style="width:70px;"> <option value="Test">TEst</option> </select> </span><span>Number: <input class="form-control" type="number" style="width:70px;" name="number[]" value="" /><button class="remove">Remove</button></p></span></div><div>';

                          objTo.appendChild(divtest)
                      }

                      
                      
                      $('#room_fileds').on("click",".remove", function(e){
                     
                          $(this).parents().eq(5).remove();
                      })




                  </script>
```